# How to generate signed apk in android studio from Previous eclipse project keystore file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore, admob

As every one of us know here that Google Admob has changed the policy for jan 23 2018. We have to use the Google Mobile Ads Sdk greater than 7. Which is possible only in Android studio. Now i have converted my previous Eclipse project to Android studio project but how can i create singed apk using Eclipse Keystore File.

Comment: Did you have .jks file with you?

Comment: Try uploading the existing key from Build>Generate Signed Apk>Choose Existing...